# giving am embed object a z-index css

Tags: css, embed, z-index

I have this fullscreen video gallery, I wanted to attach a menu to the page but i want the menu to overlap the embeded object.

I placed the menu as `z-index:1` and the embeded object is still overlapping, how can i fix this.

Comment: Is it a flash object ? If so, search for `allowtransparency` or `wmode`, depending on what you embed.

Comment: yes its a flash object

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem some time ago and this is my solution:

set also embeded object `z-index` to **-1**

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Flash, here's a good step by step how-to:
http://rijamedia.com/blog/2011/02/simple-fix-html-content-over-flash-content-in-all-browsers/